# How to connect to websocket server using boost C++

Tags: c++, boost, websocket

My websocket server URL is **ws://localhost/webstream/wsocket**
Iam trying to create a C++ websocket client that connects to this server using boost

```
tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
_pws = new websocket::stream<tcp::socket>(ioc);

// Look up the domain name
// my server is http://localhost/webstream/wsocket
_host = "localhost";
_port = 80;

auto const results = resolver.resolve(_host, std::to_string(_port));
if(results.size() == 0)
{
    std::cout<<"failed to connect to websocket server"<<std::endl;
    delete _pws;
    _pws = nullptr;
    return;
}

// Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
net::connect(_pws->next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());

// Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
_pws->set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
    [](websocket::request_type& req)
    {
        req.set(http::field::user_agent,
            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                " websocket-client-coro");
    }));
_pws->handshake(host, "/");
```

But iam unable to connect to sever.
How can i set the path "/webstream/wsocket" to connect.
'''

What I have tried:

```
i tried with
_host = "localhost/webstream/wsocket";
_port = 80;

_pws->handshake(host, "/webstream/wsocket");
```

but not getting connected
**In boost library, how can we specify the path of websocket server**

Comment: `localhost/webstream/wsocket` is not a host, so that probably won't work. Please, can you also make sure your code conforms to the [mcve] guidelines? There's way too much to guess.

Comment: using postman im able to connect to websocket server (ws://localhost/webstream/wsocket)
But my problem is i cant find a function in boost library that will connect to a path. I tried with another websocket server 
ws://localhost:5000  ==> this works fine in this code
But if it contains a subpath ..example ws://localhost:5000/wssocket
this code does not work

Comment: Why are you putting the path in the `_host` variable? That's supposed to hold the host, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to this [issue](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/813)

The right way to access the websocket url: `ws://localhost:5000/webstream/wsocket` , you need to set

```
 host_ = "localhost";
 port_ = 5000;
```

after **resolve** the endpoint and **connect**, the path `/webstream/wsocket` was needed at **handshake**

```
_pws->handshake(host, "/webstream/wsocket")
```

In this way you may successfully establish the websocket connection

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I used to connect to my url. I was sending string data from my client, and reading it in from the port using my server.

If you were able to connect to it using postman, I'm sure this will work.

```
    auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1");
    auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi("9898"));

    boost::asio::io_context ioc { 1 };

    tcp::acceptor acceptor { ioc, { address, port } };
    char againStart;

    while (1) {
        tcp::socket socket { ioc };
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        std::cout << "socket accepted" << std::endl;

        std::thread { [q = std::move(socket)]() mutable {

            boost::beast::websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws { std::move(q) };

            ws.accept();

            while (1) {
                boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;

                ws.read(buffer);
            

                auto out = boost::beast::buffers_to_string(buffer.cdata());

                stringVal = out;

                int argument = argument + 1;
                ofstream file;
                file.open("filePath.txt", ios::out | ios::app); //, ios::out | ios::app used to add to another line instead of changing entire file
                file << stringVal;
                file << argument << endl;
                file.close();

            }

        } }.detach();
```

I also kept some of the lines I used to read in data from the buffer. In theory this should work with your url as its client server binding.